# How to create a relationship in my Database for Employees that have Projects

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I am trying to wrap my head around the correct way of connecting `Employees` to `Projects` but for some reason i am having a hard time with this. I have the following so far:

```
-------------------
| Employee        |
-------------------
| EmployeeID | PK |
-------------------
| Name       |    |
-------------------
| Position   |    |
-------------------

--------------------
| Project          |
--------------------
| ProjectID   | PK |
--------------------
| Name        |    |
--------------------
| Description |    |
--------------------
```

I am going to have many `Employees` and many `Projects` and each employee can be a part of many projects while each project would have many employees attached to it. I am having an issue with how to make the connection between the two. Can someone please help talk me through this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a joining table to create two one-to-many relationships:

```
employee
employee_id   PK
```

Relates to:

```
employee_project
employee_id PK
project_id PK
```

With project also related to the above:

```
project
project_id   PK
```

So your employees can be related to your employee_project table but your projects can be related to your employee_project table too.

Having two primary keys on a table is called a [Composite Primary Key](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/6572/composite-key) (two foreign keys in this case).

Comment: Thanks for your help! That really put it in perspective. I dont know why i was having such a hard time on something so easy.

Comment: No worries, understanding the concept is the hard part.  Once you have that nailed the SQL is relatively logical utilising the necessary joins etc.  Let us know if you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

Create a Many-2-Many relationships Table like so.

```
--------------------------
| EmployeeProject        |
--------------------------
| EmployeeID        | PK |
-------------------
| ProjectID         | PK |
--------------------------
```

Your PK on this table with be Combination of `EmployeeID + ProjectID` (called Composite Primary Key).

To get Employees that have Projects, your SQL will look like so.

```
SELECT emp.* 
FROM Employee emp 
    INNER JOIN Project prj ON emp.EmployeeID = prj.EmployeeID
```

If you want to get Employees who *do not have any project*s assigned, your SQL will look like so.

```
SELECT emp.* 
FROM Employee emp 
    LEFT JOIN Project prj ON emp.EmployeeID = prj.EmployeeID
WHERE prj,EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate table where you will store EmployeeID and ProjectID as foreign keys, thus making the connection between two. (M : N relation)

Answer (score 0):

Create a third table and store EmployeeID and ProjectID   in that table, so now you can query anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need a third table which contains EmployeeID and ProjectID. Mark both IDs as primary key. You have to do a double join if you want to select them though but it's the best way to handle it.